# What kind of exception of SPL is best suited for file exceptions?

Tags: php, exceptions

When I use the Exception provided by [the SPL](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php) the options are limited. So it's hard to pick which exception would be best suited to handle File exceptions.

I know the best scenario is to write my own Exception (FileException or something), but I was wondering if the SPL could provide of some use here.

I'm currently thinking that the [RuntimeException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.runtimeexception.php) might be the best candidate, because the documentation states:

> Exception thrown if an error which can only be found on runtime occurs.

And for files this is mostly the case. For example:

- File does not exist
- File is not readable
- File cannot be opened

What is the PHP community's thought on this one?

Answer (score -2):

My suggestion is to have only `RuntimeException`. When there are a lot of exception types -- let's face it, you're using them for flow control, which is [always evil](http://wiki.c2.com/?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl).

This correlates to [fail fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) approach, which is reflected in a great [Antifragile](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0812979680) book. In essence, it means that you should expose your problems immediately and not to try to hide them. Stop code execution right where the problem happened. Log it. Be nice to your users -- say sorry. And don't propagate the error further, usually nothing good happens in this case.

This approach usually is opposed to [defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming), but it depends [how to interpret this term](http://danielroop.com/blog/2009/10/15/why-defensive-programming-is-rubbish/).